# difference between extend and include in Jade

Tags: pug

I am not able to figure out the difference between `extend` and `include`
I am confused. To me `extend` can help you extend the template,
`include` will just include it. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you are right, but the `extend` keyword gives you the effort to use block statements, you can override default blocks from an extendet layout inside your template file which extends even this layout file. All inherited files included by the keyword `include` inside your template can use this block statements too.

Here a quick example

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html(lang='de')
  head
    // Default meta block
    block meta
      meta(charset="utf-8")
      title This is the pagetitle

    // Default block for css assets
    block styles
      style.
        .somecss {
        }
  body
    // Default block for the navigation
    block navigation
      ul.my_default_nav
        li: a(href="template.html") Navitem

    // Default content block
    block main

    // Default footer block
    block footer
      p Some copyright notes
```

**template.jade**

```
extend layout.jade

block meta
  title This block overrides the default block statement

block footer
  p You can place your block somewhere in your template, during 
    | compile jade knows where to place it.

block main
  div
    p Here you can place your default content it also will be
      | replaced.
```

**The Result of all:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <!-- Default meta block-->
    <title>This block overrides the default block statement</title>
    <!-- Default block for css assets-->
    <style>
      .somecss {
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Default block for the navigation-->
    <ul class="my_default_nav">
      <li><a href="template.html">Navitem</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Default content block-->
    <div>
      <p>
        Here you can place your default content it also will bereplaced.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Default footer block-->
    <p>
      You can place your block somewhere in your template, during compile jade knows where to place it.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```